# Does protractor's multiCapabilities using same type browser considered an isolated environment?

Tags: protractor, cucumber

Recently, I am configing `protractor.conf.js` to make the end 2 end tests run in parallel for different kind of users to reduce running time.

However, the app is stateful and storing login information at local storage.

Right now, the end 2 end tests do a lot less time to run, but sometimes it passed, and sometimes it failed.

I am suspecting that due to the stateful nature of app making it failed.

So, when protractor starts 3 chrome instances, are each of the instance considered in its isolated environment? If not, is there any way to achieve this? I already tried with

```js
chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--incognito"]
    },
```

to make each Chrome in incognito mode yet still getting inconsistent test result.

*Versions*

- protractor ^5.3.2
- protractor-cucumber-framework ^5.0.0

Comment: We use multicapabiliites as well and we are not seeing any issues. Each instance runs in its own state but we use to clear cookies in the start of any spec file using below.
    browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
    browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
    browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();

Comment: The major concern is still does it cause side affects on other instance? For example, chrome1 is executing, then chrome2 launches and stored user information into session/local storage. Does this sort of behavior would affect chrome1's ongoing specs?

Comment: Nope, it should not affect other chrome instance. The session info will be independent on other instances for sure.

Comment: Including localStorage as well?